# Display lighting:spinner component during component render cycle

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Examples of `lightning:spinner` usage that I've seen are used for delays in controller logic processing, ie waiting on an asynchronous callout. But what I'm trying to solve for is being able to show the spinner while the actual component markup is rendering.

For example, I have a child component that builds a complex table using nested `aura:iteration` and `aura:if` tags, and takes 5-10 seconds for the actual table to be rendered on the page, while the controller logic completes instantly.

I can't figure out how to turn on the spinner at the beginning of the render process, then turn it off after.

**My attempt**

I tried using two standard event handlers for `init` and `render`, which I understood to be fired on either end of the rendering process. I paired `lightning:spinner` with an `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">`, then in each of those handler methods I set `showSpinner` to true and false, respectively.

component:

```
<aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>

 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Page loading..." aura:id="loadingSpinner"/>
</aura:if>
```

controller:

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    console.log('doinit fired');
    component.set("v.showSpinner", true);
},

onRender: function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('onRender fired');
    component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
},
```

**Outcome**

Visually: About 5 seconds pass before the page finishes rendering (during which the SF page framework displays, including the parent lightning component, but the table inside the child component does not), then the table appears. The spinner does not show at all.

Console Log: 
I expected that onRender wouldn't fire till after the table was displaying, but apparently not, because immediately upon component creation and prior to the table displaying, the following console log lines displayed:

```
doinit fired 
onRender fired  
onRender fired
```

Then, immediately after the table finished rendering, onRender fired three more times.

So that explains why the spinner doesn't show. The first onRender fires instantly, turning off the spinner.

What I don't get is why `onRender` is firing five times during the initial rendering of the table, when the data object that populates the table hasn't been manipulated by code or user entry yet.

How can I ensure that the spinner isn't hidden until after the table component truly finishes rendering? is there a an event other than `init` that flags the start of any individual render process, since there are clearly several rerenderings on the initial page load?

Comment: Something I do often is to show the spinner by default so when the component starts the load the spinner is already displayed. Then I will hide the spinner once I have gotten all the information and stored it into an attribute. You could try doing it a similar way. Is there an attribute or something that you can look at to decide if everything has been loaded?

Comment: Zack, therein lies my difficulty, because all logic and variables have been loaded prior to the actual rendering of the table, so I'm not sure what I can check against to determine whether the rendering is complete, other than an event that actually fires upon completion.

Comment: Have you read through this? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm

Comment: Also maybe look into custom rendered https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm

Comment: Yep, have been through both of those, it's how I learned about the render event! I may need to take a closer look at a custom renderer, but I would expect that the standard rendering engine would have a similar set of events that fire on init, on start of render, on completion of render, etc. I can't find the 'on start of render' equivalent.

Comment: Yeah this is tricky. If you could create a custom rendered function that would fire when each component has rendered then maybe you could monitor it from the parent and stop the spinner then? I am not experienced with custom rendered so I will leave this for another user.

Comment: Have you tried using <aura:method> to load the table after the page has been loaded? What you can do is, let the component and the child component load without building your table on init. Define an aura:method in your child component and let the handler of that method build the table. You can call this method on the onInit method of your parent component. What should happen is, your component will load without the table and with the spinner already spinning, then the OnInit method will cause your component to build the table and then hide the spinner.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution Aayush, thanks. I just implemented something different that got me what I need that I'll post now.

Comment: Aayush, actually I think I see the same issue with your approach: the aura:method will handle the logic of building the table, which is nearly instantaneous and completes far before the actual rendering of the table. So when the spinner is turned off at the end of that method the table still will not have loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Using a window.setTimeout() worked for me.

```
helper.displaySpinner();

window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){
    // Your async code here
    helper.hideSpinner();
}), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way to get my specific situation to work.

My table component is actually a grandchild of the top level parent component. The middle component is created dynamically using `$A.createComponent` on the grandparent, and the grandchild is inserted statically into the middle component using `<c:grandchild_Component>`

Instead of trying to control and display the spinner on the middle or grandchild components, I moved it up to the parent component. `showSpinner` is set to true by default, and the attribute is set to false within the callback function of the `$A.createComponent` that creates the middle component, like such:

```
$A.createComponent("c:middle_component", {
                                "aura:id": "step3",
                                },
                                function (childcmp, status, errorMessage) {
                                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                        component.set("v.content", childcmp);
                                        component.set("v.currentStep", 'step3');
                                        console.log('spinner turned off');
                                        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
                                    } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                                        console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
                                    } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                                        console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
```

One peculiarity I've noted in doing this is that the grandchild's `init` and `render` methods don't fire until after the callback from it's parent component is completed. I would have thought that $A.createComponent wouldn't be considered complete until all children components of the created components were also created and rendered.